# How to delete COOKIE in YII which is set in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, yii

i//Setting cookie in codeigniter
  In codeigniter:

```
    $this->load->helper('cookie');     
    $cookie = array(
                'name'   => 'social',
                'value'  => 'logout',
                'expire' =>  86500,
                'secure' => false
            );
   $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

In YII:

```
  if(isset($_COOKIE['social'])&&$_COOKIE['social']=='logout'){
  //Clearing cookie in yii
        Yii::app()->request->cookies->clear();
        Yii::app()->user->logout();         
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure php approach is to set the cookie expiration to a time in the past.

`setcookie('social', '', time() - 3600)`

This assumes the cookie is being set on the same domain.

see http://php.net/setcookie

Comment: Are the cookies on the same domain? Do you use the cookie in the same request? If so you might want to run unset($_COOKIE['social']) after the setcookie function call.

Comment: Yes both are on same domain.I also tries unset($_COOKIE['social']) but still its not deleting.